# How to move files to RECYCLE.BIN in powershell WITHOUT interactive dialog in case of file busy or other error?

Tags: powershell, batch-processing

How to move files to RECYCLE.BIN in powershell **WITHOUT interactive dialog** in case when the file is busy or any other error?
I tried to use

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem]::DeleteFile($f.FullName,'OnlyErrorDialogs','SendToRecycleBin')
```

This will suspend execution and show me an error dialog.

Same is with using COM:

```
function safeRemove($fileFullName)
{
    $Error.Clear()
    $shell = new-object -comobject "Shell.Application"
    $path = $fileFullname
    $item = $shell.Namespace(0).ParseName("$path")
    $item.InvokeVerb("delete")
}
```

**Both methods are unacceptable if it shoud run in a batch job.**
And of course I'm using
 $ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"

Anybody can help?

Comment: To use the Recycle Bin you must use shell commands. IO commands do not use the Recycle Bin. See FOF_NOERRORUI (and the other UI suppression flags) at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shfileopstructa. For your second code example you are using libraries that call the underlying functions in a very indirect way. But those libraries were designed to be easy to use not full featured or desgined to be mimicking the UI,.